# trying to use LIKE Mysql on wordpress $wpdb->prepare

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and trying to use LIKE in Mysql. In my code below, I have followed this Wordpress reference:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb/esc_like

but nothing echoes out. What did I miss?

```html
<?php
global $wpdb;
$keyword ="apple";
$keyword = $wpdb->esc_like( $keyword );
$keyword = '%' . $keyword . '%';    
$sql = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE keyword LIKE %s"),$keyword);

print_r($sql);
?>
```

Comment: normally, we write something like this SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE keyword LIKE '%apple%'. But with wordpress prepare, we need to follow their code, so i follow their reference, but nothing echo out.

Answer (score 1):

According to wordpress reference `prepare` requires 2 arguments.

[Please note: As of 3.5, wpdb::prepare() enforces a minimum of 2 arguments](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/)

`<?php $sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'query' , value_parameter[, value_parameter ... ] ); ?>`

Answer (score -1):

Try this out simple get_results

```
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE keyword LIKE '%apple%'", ARRAY_A );
```